# Application navigated to home screen when tapped dismiss on devices low battery alert in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

These are the steps where this scenario is occurring:

1. I deployed my app and I navigated to several screens.
2. Due to low battery of my device I got a low battery alert.
3. When I tapped dismiss button from the low battery aler, My app is automatically navigating to the Home screen (i.e first screen)

Can anyone suggest me what might be the problem.

Comment: What code do you have in your appDelegate specifically the methods used during state changes. i.e. applicationDidEnterBackground: etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever these system dialog pops up, your app though still in forground becomes inactive. And once you dismiss it, it becomes active again. If my guess is right, you must be doing something in applicationDidBecomeActive delegate method. You simply need to check that method and fix it.

Comment: u r right.I am doing some stuff in applicationDidBecomeActive method, because of that I got this issue. Now the problem got resolved. Thank you.